# Sections inside of section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My starting point has been a page with four sections like [this](https://codepen.io/szeconku/pen/XERqPB).

I have tried to add three "inner sections" inside each section like [this](https://codepen.io/szeconku/pen/dedRBR).

I would like to achieve the following but I don't know how:

- The three inner sections should be visible only on click. So the start image should look like [this](https://codepen.io/szeconku/pen/XERqPB). After clicking on, say, Section 1 the three inner sections should appear.
- A click on, say, Section 1 should make Sections A-C visible. A click on Section A should make the listbox visible. A click on Section A should go back to Section 1 with the overview of Section A-C. To go back to Sections 1-4 I'll create a back button. This I know how to do.

Currently, the code that does the navigation back and forth between sections is:

```
$('.section').on('click', function(e){
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded'); 
  $('.innersection').on('click',   function(e){  
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded'); 
  });
});  

$('.section').on('click', function(e){
  $(this).toggleClass('collapsed'); 
});  

$('.innersection').on('click',   function(e){  
    $(this).toggleClass('collapsed'); 
});
```

Any help is appreciated. Thx.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The two bullet points.

Comment: Those bullets are statements about what you want.  Not *specific* questions about your difficulties in achieving them

Comment: To be honest, I also had some problems understand what exactly the real question was. I do think @Pointy has a point. Also, the code provided does not give much insight to what the OP has tired so far and what problems he encountered.

Comment: I think the title about using iframes was throwing people off...  Now that the question is heavily edited it makes much more sense.

Comment: And so it happens again, comments are more about discussing if the OP explained his problem according to the SO rules or not. How about helping him out?

Comment: @Brainfeeder I was honestly having trouble understanding the question which made finding a solution difficult.

Comment: @Brainfeeder  Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.  To reinforce this, we *have* to ask users to ask specific questions about what specific problems they are trying to solve.  Not just accept "I want X" questions.

Comment: @Taplar I understand, but maybe SO should consider having a comment section at triage or something so the discussion about ‘is this a good question or not’ can be kept separate. I’m tired of reading through useless comments just to find the OP’s extra info on the question.

Comment: @JonathanRys okay, I must admit that this was hard to grasp what he was trying to do.

Comment: This isn't extra information about this question though.  It is clarification of an overly broad question.

Comment: @Taplar true that

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve it with css like this:

```
.innersection {
  display: none;
}

.section.collapsed>.innersection {
  display: none;
}

.section.expanded>.innersection {
  display: block;
}
```

The solution to the second problem can be solved in a similar way.

Comment: Thx. It solved the first question/bullet/problem. I'll continue to work on the second question/bullet/problem.